# Algebraic Fundamental Group $π_1(U)$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, galois-theory, fundamental-groups

I have a $1 \frac{1}{2}$questions about two examples introduced in Szamuely's "Galois Groups and Fundamental Groups" in the excerpt below (see page 122):

[image]

Let $X$ be an integral proper normal $k$-curve
with function field $K$, and $U ⊂ X$ a nonempty open subset. The construction below describes how to obtain a Galois extension $K_U \vert K$:

[image]

Then we define the algebraic
fundamental group $π_1(U)$ of $U$ to be the Galois group $Gal (K_U |K)$.

QUESTION:

I don't understand how 4.6.7 and 4.6.10 imply for *algebraic fundamental groups* $\pi_1(\mathbb{P}^1_k)=\pi_1(\mathbb{A}^1_k)$ in example 1.

4.6.10 describes invariance of $\pi_1$ under base change by field extensions. 4.6.7 tells that is essentially the profinite completion of the topological fundamental group of the Riemann surface associated with $U$.

Why does this provide $\pi_1(\mathbb{P}^1_k)=\pi_1(\mathbb{A}^1_k)$?

Futhermore regarding example 2: I know that $\mathbb{P}^1_{\mathbb{C}} \cong S^2$ so $\mathbb{P}^1_{\mathbb{C}}\backslash \{0, \infty\} \cong S^1$ but what about $\mathbb{P}^1_{k}$ for arbitrary algebraically closed $k$ of char $0$?

Here we have thm 4.6.7:

[image]

Comment: By invariance along algebraically closed field extension $\pi_1(\mathbb{A}^1_k)=\pi_1(\mathbb{A}^1_{\overline{Q}})=\pi_1(\mathbb{A}^1_{\mathbb{C}})$. So it is enough to compute $\pi_1(\mathbb{A}^1_{\mathbb{C}})$, but by 4.6.7 this is the profinite completion of $\pi_1(\mathbb{A}^1(\mathbb{C}))$ which is trivial. So $\pi_1(\mathbb{A}^1_k)$ is trivial. The same argument works for $\mathbb{P}^1_k$.

Comment: @Roland: ah ok so the author calculated $\pi_1(\mathbb{A}^1_k)$ and $\pi_1(\mathbb{P}^1_k)$ ***separately*** and came to conclusion that both are trivial using the base change and fundamnetal group of $S^2$ resp that of the complex line. yes, then it was indeed a stupid question since firstly I had in mind that he used a "mysterious" ***reduction step*** from $\pi_1(\mathbb{P}^1_k)$ to $\pi_1(\mathbb{A}^1_k)$ and ***then*** observes that $\pi_1(\mathbb{A}^1_k)$ is trivial

Comment: Just to point out--in positive characteristic the projective line is still simply connected, but the same is not true of the affine line.